# Regex replace keeping part of a string and adding data

Tags: regex, replace

I have this file with thousands of records (more thank 300.000) and I have to replace all the occurrences of a particular string but keeping some of it.

I'll give you an example, the string would be

\123

\34565

\923

..etc

so basically I would have to convert these strings in to

'|''|'123'

'|''|'34565'

'|''|'923'

does anyone have a quick solution for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\\(\d+)
```

You should use `g`(global) modifier to match all. So your final regex would become:

```
/\\(\d+)/g
```

and replace it with:

```
'|''|'$1'
```

Demo:http://regex101.com/r/yO3xQ6

Comment: I'm trying to use sed do you know the syntax for the command with this regex ?

Comment: No, I haven't even heard of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Regex        - \\(\d+)
Replace with - '|''|'\1'
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/yQ8oM4)